# ERROR: continuous aggregate view must include a valid time bucket function

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm encountering an issue while working with PostgreSQL and TimescaleDB. I'm attempting to create a continuous aggregate view, but I keep receiving the following error message:
`ERROR: continuous aggregate view must include a valid time bucket function`

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW BN_hourly_bars WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 hour', datetime, '15 minutes'::INTERVAL) AS bucket_start,
    stock_code,
    exchange_code,
    product_type,
    expiry_date,
    "right" AS right_option,
    strike_price,
    FIRST(open, datetime) AS open_price,
    MAX(high) AS max_high_price,
    MIN(low) AS min_low_price,
    LAST(close, datetime) AS close_price,
    SUM(volume) AS total_volume,
    SUM(open_interest) AS open_interest
FROM
    ticks_table2
GROUP BY
    bucket_start,
    stock_code,
    exchange_code,
    product_type,
    expiry_date,
    right_option,
    strike_price;
```

candle start time is : 9:15

Let me know how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error might be due to the second argument of the **time_bucket** function, which specifies the duration. In your query, you're using '**1 hour**' as the duration, which seems fine, but you're also specifying **'15 minutes'::INTERVAL** as an additional parameter.

Try removing '**15 minutes'::INTERVAL** from the **time_bucket** function and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: if i remove interval i get startime as 9:00 but sesssion starts from 9:15. so i need  candles 9:15 to 10:15, 10:15 to 11:15 like that..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the arguments order but in the function return which is not immutable.

Check the type of the timestamp column.

Comment: its timestamp without timezone.. select query working only create not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the short answer. This is a problem widely discussed in the Timescale community.

The problem is related to the immutable vs not immutable time bucket function signature dealing with different types of data. So, in resume timestamp is not immutable and timestamptz is immmutable.

Let's navigate on it:

```
SELECT p.proname
     , PG_GET_FUNCTION_ARGUMENTS(p.oid)
     , CASE p.provolatile
           WHEN 'i'
               THEN 'IMMUTABLE'
           WHEN 's'
               THEN 'STABLE'
           WHEN 'v'
               THEN 'VOLATILE'
       END AS volatility
FROM pg_proc      p
JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = 'pg_catalog'
  AND p.proname = 'time_bucket';
```

will return

```sql
  proname  |      pg_get_function_arguments       | volatility
-----------+--------------------------------------+------------
 timestamp | date                                 | IMMUTABLE
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone             | STABLE
 timestamp | date, time without time zone         | IMMUTABLE
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone, integer | IMMUTABLE
```

As you can see timestamp is not immutable

but if you see `timestamptz` it' is immutable.

```
 timestamptz | timestamp with time zone, integer | IMMUTABLE
```

Maybe this snippet can also shed some light.

```sql
SELECT pg_typeof(timezone('UTC', '2024-01-05')::timestamptz)
```

**Resolution**: Change your column type to timestamptz.